# How can i show post_class() within output loop?

Tags: php, post-class

I am trying to use show `post_class()` within $output loop.Though i tried it different way i failed.

### Here is my codes

```
$output = '<div ';
post_class('blog-list-vertical-content');
$output .= '" id=' . get_the_ID() . '>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`get_post_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_class)

From [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_class):

> `get_post_class()` is not simply a non-echoing alternative to
>   `post_class()`. `get_post_class()` does not return a string, but an array
>   that must be processed to produce text similar to what is echoed by
>   `post_class()`.

So

```
$classes = get_post_class();
$output = '<div id="' . get_the_ID() . '" class="' . implode(" ", $classes) . '"></div>';
```